# Button opens link in the same tab

Tags: html

I am working on a website that I can choose a brand from the dropdown list and press go and be sent to the company's website. I want the link to open in a new tab but the every option in the dropdown has a different link. I am using html and bootstrap This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function goToNewPage() {
            var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
            if (url != 'none') {
                window.location = url;
            }
            window.open(hrefLocation);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

        <p class="ps-4">Choose a Brand:</p>
        <form class="ps-4">
            <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">

                <option value="https://www.apple.com/">Apple</option>
                <option value="https://www.samsung.com/eg">Samsung</option>
                <option value="https://www.huawei.com/">Huawei</option>
                <option value="https://www.oppo.com/">Oppo</option>

            </select>
            <input type=button value="Go" onclick=" goToNewPage('_blank') " />

        </form>
```

Comment: And what's the issue exactly? Have you checked to see what value you get for `url`?

Comment: You try `window.open(hrefLocation);` but `hrefLocation` is not defined anywhere. Don't you mean `url`?

Comment: You can improve the quality of this question if you provide a bit more information. The title gives us the expected behaviour, but what's actually happening? What have you tried? Which line of code isn't behaving the way you expect it to?

Comment: @j08691 the link opens in the same tab, I want  it in a different tab.

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to open form on new page then you can use like this replace url

```
<form name="frmSearch" action="{url}" target="_blank">
   <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
                <option value="https://www.apple.com/">Apple</option>
                <option value="https://www.samsung.com/eg">Samsung</option>
                <option value="https://www.huawei.com/">Huawei</option>
                <option value="https://www.oppo.com/">Oppo</option>

            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Go"  />
</form>
```

or if you want it on button

```
<input type="button" value="Go"  onclick="openInNewTab(url)" />

function openInNewTab(url) {
 window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}
```